# Inserting a blank line for a certain amount of columns only and aligning two sets of columns with diff amounts of row data correctly

Tags: vba, excel

Hi Everyone I am hoping someone to help me, it seems like a complicated one to me so lets see:

I have to compare two amounts of information for errors line by line for price differences.  The excel document is 15000 rows long so hence why I need a macro! Columns A to I hold the the first document information, then K to Q has the second amount of document info. The comparison needs to happen between Column A and Q which have matching "shipper"numbers. Each shipper number has a certain number of part numbers below it which each contain the info I need to compare. The problem is one shipper may have more or less parts on document one compared to document two so I cant just run a insert line using vba as it will cut document 2 incorrect. Is it possbile 1.) insert a line after each shipper changes in document one by looking at column A (Shipper no) and running it until Col I and at the same time (or after) inserting a blank line for documents two looking at column Q AND is it possible to try match up each shipper so they start on the same line to compare properly without me going through and aligning them up manually??Please see link below for example of what I am saying. If it doesnt work, please let me know and I'll make a plan.

Thank you in advance!

[image: Shipper Excel Example]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSdLX.jpg):

Comment: So if I understood correctly, the first thing that should happen is to insert a "row" of cells above K5:Q5. What you can do is to just record that action and see the VBA code behind it. Then you can use that to build a loop through your tables and perform it for either A:I or K:Q.

Comment: What comparison are you trying to make? Are you trying to make sure the prices are the same? Why not let the macro do the comparison as well and then put the results on another worksheet? Just a suggestion. :-)

Comment: @Thanks Sun I was hoping you could help with the code on how to loop it correctly as I just know how to record the macro but not how to manipulate it as I dont know enough..how would you tell it in code to insert a line only at a change in shipper over certain columns?

Comment: @Brian, that would make my life easier as I do need to compare the prices but the problem is a part can come up number of times in different shippers with diff prices, so to be accurate I need to first match the shipper number together (which has certain numbers of parts in it as seen in picture) then compare price on each parts in that shipper...does that make sense? If you could help with what the code is to do this I will be forever grateful!